# Add a generated column using alter table statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-tables

I'm not able to add a generated column using an `alter table` statement in SQL Server 2017. I'm trying to create a temporal table from an existing table as discussed in the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15

But `alter table` shows an error:

> Incorrect syntax near generated

```
GO 

ALTER TABLE InsurancePolicy 
ADD SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN
 CONSTRAINT DF_SysStart DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME() , SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN CONSTRAINT DF_SysEnd DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'), 
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime); 

GO 

ALTER TABLE InsurancePolicy SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = History.InsurancePolicy));
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share the SQL statement you tried and the exact error you recieved.

Comment: GO

ALTER TABLE InsurancePolicy
    ADD
        SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN
            CONSTRAINT DF_SysStart DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME()
      , SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN
            CONSTRAINT DF_SysEnd DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
        PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime);
GO

ALTER TABLE InsurancePolicy
    SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = History.InsurancePolicy));

Comment: Getting error as incorrect syntax near generated keyword

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: There you go ,have edited the question

Comment: I cannot reproduce your syntax error. [This fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4667a64fcfb0780734f771f427b61dfa) applies the documentation page you provided. Please include your _full_ script so we can attempt to reproduce this: the complete definition of your current non-temporal table and the exact statement you ran (I doubt your existing real world table is called `InsurancePolicy` just like in the documentation example?).